# How can I measure the association between 40 binary variables?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, binary-data

I have 40 binary (0/1) variables with 70 observations and would like to measure the association of occurrences between them. Is the presence or absence of a variable is associated with the presence / absence of another one? I believe I would be trying to do a multivariate analysis but with binary variables instead of continuous.

Comment: Are you only looking to compare two variables at a time?  If so, you could simply create a matrix of conditional probabilities i.e. given that variable A is 1, what is the probability that B is 1.

Comment: Wouldn't that be multivariate logistic regression? The rule of thumb is 10 observations for each variable and so if you are looking at 40 then you analysis will most likely be underpowered to detect any significant difference (even if present... Type II error).

Comment: @user62117 I want to compare all 40 variables at once against each other. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @abousetta Thanks for your comment, I will compare only the 7 most relevant ones then. How would you suggest doing it? Multiple logistic regression requires that I define one variable as the dependent variable, and the rest as independent/explanatory; should I then run 7 models (one for each variable as the DV)?

Comment: Would performing a series of McNemar tests for each combination of variables be a simpler way of getting a sense of which variables are consistent with each other?